# Cannot get VSCode to suggest html data attributes (data-rel, data-theme, data-position etc...)

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is it possible to configure **VScode** to suggest html data attributes like **intelliJ** does out of the box?

Intellij: html data attribute

[image: html data attribute]

VSCode: Nothing!

[image: Nothing!]

Comment: Welcome, @kosan_81.  I added the visual-studio-code tag, and removed the jquery tags, since it seems this question is really about VS Code.  Even though you have VSCode in the title, many people search for questions to answer by tags, so this should help you attract answers from users of VS Code.

Comment: I don't see anything in the extension marketplace that adds this feature. My guess is because they are user defined, nothing HTML 5 specific.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply,actually I think most of them are jQuery & jQuery Mobile specific, but having said that intelliJ IDEA comes with these suggestions out of the box. I tried some linters, but they only add suggestions for css classes and not these tag attributes I need.... :(

Answer (score 1):

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-data-extension allows you to create a json file with suggestions and documentation for those suggestions.  That link should guide you in the right direction.

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/02/24/custom-data-format